# Why are my CoffeeScript/backbone.js events not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, backbone.js

I'm trying to familiarize myself with CoffeeScript and backbone.js, and I must be missing something.

This CoffeeScript:

```
MyView  = Backbone.View.extend 
   events: { 
     "click" : "testHandler" 
   } 

   testHandler: -> 
     console.log "click handled" 
     return false 

 view = new MyView {el: $('#test_container')} 
 view.render()
```

Generates the following JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  var MyView, view;
  MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
      "click": "testHandler"
    },
    testHandler: function() {
      console.log("click handled");
      return false;
    }
  });
  view = new MyView({
    el: $('#test_container')
  });
  view.render;
}).call(this);
```

But the `click` event does not fire `testHandler` when I click in `test_container`.

If I change the output JavaScript to:

```
$(function() {
  var MyView, view;
  MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
      "click": "testHandler"
    },
    testHandler: function() {
      console.log("click handled");
      return false;
    }
  });
  view = new MyView({
    el: $('#test_container')
  });
  view.render;
});
```

Removing the `call(this)` and appending the `$`, everything works as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery. Do you want to add the jQuery tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(function () {}).call(this);
```

is just a way to immediately invoke an anonymous function while specifying a receiver. It works basically this same way as:

```
this.method = function () {};
this.method();
```

`$(function () {})`, at least in jQuery, is shorthand for

```
$(document).ready(function () {})
```

which runs the given function when the DOM tree has been fully constructed. It seems like this is the necessary condition for your `Backbone.View.extend` function to work properly.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks, and this whole time I was thinking (function (){}).call(this) was the same as $(function(){}).  Makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 5):

For using CoffeeScript and jQuery together for application scripts, put your code in this sort of template:

```
$ = jQuery
$ ->

  MyView = Backbone.View.extend
    events:
      "click": "testHandler"
    testHandler: ->
      console.log "click handled"
      false

  view = new MyView el: $('#test_container')
  view.render()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using CoffeeScript class declaration syntax, e.g.:

```
class BacklogView extends Backbone.View
  constructor: (@el) ->
    this.delegateEvents this.events

  events:
    "click" : "addStory"

  # callbacks
  addStory: ->
    console.log 'it works!'
```

Comment: I've found better solution some time later.. and today StackOverflow reminded about itself (I earned some badge :)
So better solution is to call super in the very first line of the constructor method body and abandon call to this.delegateEvents.
Good luck ;)

Comment: having the constructor as in your example with super() as the first line worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when the view, or at least view.el is dynamically generated?  You can call the view.delegateEvents() method to manually set the eventhandlers.

Here's similar coffeescript for rendering a ChildView in a ParentView then delegating the childView's events.

```
window.ParentView = Backbone.View.extend
  addOne: (thing) ->
    view = new ChildView({model: thing})
    this.el.append view.render().el 
    view.delegateEvents()
```